# recieving gps data sent to webservice on port 80

Tags: php, gps, nmea

I'm buying a gps tracker which is able to sent its GPS data (NMEA) to a designated ip/hostname and port.

Since i do not own a server, I was wondering what would happen if I configured the device to send its data to 1.1.1.1:80 where the default php-webservice is running.

So far so good. But how can I then use the sended data? When i post a form it is in $_POST. But in what variable can I find the sent NMEA data?
recieving gps data sent to webservice on port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GPS device is not an HTTP client. It does not "speak the language" of the service that usually runs on port 80 (that is, a web server).

Instead, install a daemon like [`gpsd`](http://gpsd.berlios.de/).

And I have no idea what you mean by `1.1.1.1`. I bet you don't own a machine with that address.

Comment: The GPS device supports TCP and UDP, at least that is what the manual says. The 1.1.1.1 ip adres is just a fictive one, i whished I owned it :)

Comment: @stUrb: If you "do not own a server", whose is this fictional device?

Comment: I only have a hosting on a server. So I don't _own_ a server and that's why I don't have the privileges to run some more additional daemons like gpsd. Therefore i was wondering if it was possible to use it on my web service.

Comment: @stUrb: Unless your GPS device has specific web client functionality, no. You could run a PHP script that listens on an auxiliary port for plain-text data, but this is akin to running a daemon and it sounds like you wouldn't have the ability to keep that running.

Comment: @stUrb: The commercial spam isn't required! Good luck.

Comment: Sorry about the 'spam', it wasn't meant to be spam, but only for the reference. The strange thing it says to send a plain text string through tcp or udp. Just like a post var....

Comment: @stUrb: An HTTP POST var _isn't_ a "plain text string [sent] through TCP or UDP", though. It's encapsulated within an HTTP request.